# Change cursor position in UITextview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I have added `UIImageView` in `UITextView` using the `addSubview` method. Now I want to change the cursor position so that it starts entering any string after the `UIImageview` position.

Comment: first welcome to stackoverflow and share your code :)

Comment: and what you want ??? explain more.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same for my Custom UITextField.

```
    cursor=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cursor.png"]];


    CGFloat width =  [myTextFied.text sizeWithFont:myTextFied.font].width;
    cursor.frame=CGRectMake(width+1, 7, 2, 20);
    [myTextFied addSubview:cursor];
```